# Save Uilabel with text color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to save image with Uilabeltextfields.
I could save them but all textfields are black.
I try to change from attributes inspector but nothing change.
Anybody can help me to save Uilabel text fields with white color.
also I need bold font characters.

Thank you.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mainImage.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.goalkeeperImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.goalkeeperImage.frame.origin.x, self.goalkeeperImage.frame.origin.y, self.goalkeeperImage.frame.size.width, self.goalkeeperImage.frame.size.height)];
    [self.goalkeeperText.text drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.goalkeeperText.frame.origin.x, self.goalkeeperText.frame.origin.y, self.goalkeeperText.frame.size.width,self.goalkeeperText.frame.size.height) withAttributes:nil ];
    [self.datelabeltext.text drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.datelabeltext.frame.origin.x, self.datelabeltext.frame.origin.y, self.datelabeltext.frame.size.width,self.datelabeltext.frame.size.height) withAttributes: nil  ];

    UIImage *SaveImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(SaveImage, self,@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: Use `attributedText` instead of `text`. Then you can setup the attribute text with whatever font attributes and colors you need.

Comment: I have made change as;      [self.datelabeltext.attributedText drawWithRect:CGRectMake(self.datelabeltext.frame.origin.x, self.datelabeltext.frame.origin.y, self.datelabeltext.frame.size.width,self.datelabeltext.frame.size.height) options:@selector(fontAttributes)  context:nil];              It works but Xcode gives me a warning " 'Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'SEL' to parameter of type 'NSStringDrawingOptions' (aka 'enum NSStringDrawingOptions')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the images and labels you are trying to render are contained within a single view(and no other objects are present) you can use this code to capture the containing view:

```
// Draw the high resolution image to the context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[[drawView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *ViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Save the high resolution image as a png
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ViewImage);
[pngData writeToFile:@"__Path__/image@2x.png" atomically:NO];

// Draw the low resolution image to the context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawView.bounds.size);
[[drawView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
ViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Save the low resolution image as a png
pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ViewImage);
[pngData writeToFile:@"__Path__/image.png" atomically:NO];
```

You probably don't need the code to save the image as a png, you can just use `ViewImage` as the UIImage you're passing along to another function. This is just the code I use to save a view as a png.